# jquery transit inconsistency

Tags: jquery, transition, jquery-transit

Ive put this example together to show a problem I am having with jquery transit. What I want to happen is for the UL to seem like it is infinitely going up.

Youll notice, I have that it shifts 146 pixels (the height of an li) every time you click the "up" button. When it gets to the end of the ul, it is supposed to set the ul back to the start, and then shift 146px using:

```
$('.test').css({y:ulHeight}).delay(8).transition({y:'+=146px'});
```

According to jquery transit, the transition part of that should not execute until the css part is complete, but it only works about 10% of the time. The more time in between clicking the up button, the better it gets.

I put a delay in there hoping it would help, but it doesn't seem to. If I put a really long delay in there, it works, but then there is a noticeable delay that looks bad.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/livinzlife/RMKQQ/

Comment: you can use focus and it will save you the calculation